# How to fix header file not found when Archive build on Xcode?

Tags: xcode, macos, flutter, dart

Hello I develop this iOS app use `Dart` language.
recently, Develop completed.
To upload an iOS app to your AppStore, need to set it up on that site.

https://developer.apple.com/

https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/

and I try Build -> Archive click on Xcode
but fail message

`ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:6:9: 
'device_info/DeviceInfoPlugin.h' file not found`

How to fix header file not found message on Xcode?
thanks

Answer (score 5):

I just discovered that this class of error can also come about when you inadvertently open the project file `Runner.xcodeproj` instead of the workspace file `Runner.xcworkspace`.

Answer (score 0):

Two options

1.Using the command line build your project using "flutter create -i swift appname".

2.If you've already created a project you'll have to add 'use_frameworks!' to your podfile.

Option 2 might not be the best option because there is a cocoapods issue that causes certain packages like OneSignal will cause the app build to fail.

Comment: I've run into this issue and my podfile already has 'use_frameworks!' in it